# Finding values a and b to get PMF with certain mean and standard deviation

Tags: self-study, bayesian, inference

Suppose that the proportion θ of defective items in a large manufactured lot is known to be either 0.05 or 0.15, and the prior pmf of θ is as follows: ξ(0.05) = a and ξ(0.15) = b. Suppose also that when n = 10 items are selected at random from the lot, it is found that X = 5 of them are defective.

(a) Determine the values of a and b such that the prior pmf of θ has mean 0.1 and standard deviation 0.05.

(b) Determine the posterior pmf of θ using the selected a and b in the previous problem.

(c) What are the posterior mean and standard deviation of θ?

I am unsure where to start. Would a and b both equal to 0.05 because the mean 0.1 is between 0.05 and 0.15. Can I assume normal distribution here?

Comment: **Hint for (a):** Since $\mathbb{P}(\theta=0.05)=a=1-\mathbb{P}(\theta=0.15)$ and the mean of $\theta$ is $\mathbb{E}[\theta]=0.1$, the value of $a$ is...

Comment: @Xi'an Is a = 0.5 because 0.1 is between 0.05 and 0.15?

Comment: 0.08 is also between 0.05 and 0.15... would $a=0.5$ if the mean were 0.08 instead?

Comment: @jbowman if mean were 0.08, a would not equal to 0.5 because 0.08 is not midway between 0.05 and 0.15?

Comment: Ah, "midway".  That's a more precise response than "between", and a better one.  What is $b$ given that $a = 0.5$?  What is the standard deviation given $a = 0.5$?

Comment: @jbowman b would also be 0.5 because probability must be equal to 1. So P(0.05) = 0.5. P(0.15) = 1- P(0.05) = 1-0.5 = 0.5. Can you hive me a hint on standard deviation?

Comment: If you know the formula for calculating a standard deviation, just apply it.  You have, for example, $x = 0.05$ with probability $0.5$ and $x = 0.15$ with probability $0.5$, and you know the mean is $0.1$.